# Weird error with tomcat7 service

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, tomcat7, docker

I'm running tomcat7 inside a docker container. When I run this command :

```
service tomcat7 start
```

It says:

```
Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7 [fail]
```

But I see the 'It works!' page and I see my application running. The logs in /var/log/tomcat7 don't show anything unusual. Does it matter if it says it failed to start?

I don't have any other instance of tomcat7 running on port 8080.

Comment: Please provide details on your init system and tomcat7 init script/job

Answer (score 2):

`service` implies that you're running init or systemd.  This is very unusual in a docker container.  I've never seen it working.  Normally you'd either run a single process (e.g. RUN /usr/bin/tomcat7), or manage multiple processes with supervisord.  https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

Comment: When I run my container I run /bin/bash so I can do modifications in my container. Once inside container, I run service tomcat7 start.